# Can a DataTemplate be applied by type to a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a `DataTemplate` for a custom class which should be used to display the contents of the file type.

Here is a sample one placed in the window's resource dictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="namespace:Handle">
    <Border>
        <TextBlock>This is a static data template</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible for a `DataGridTemplateColumn` `CellTemplate` to reference the given template by type and not by an `x:Key`?

It works by Key if I use something like

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="The file name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate }" />
```

that's fine, but can I do a type binding?

The DataGrid has **no** auto generated columns and not every column should be templated by the template above.

---

**Edit:** This is a response to @Anatoliy Nikolaev : I think your answer is quite not the solution I was expected as I am just using a key. Here is a sample that outlines the behaviour:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type system:Object}" DataType="{x:Type dataTemplateOnType:Handle}">
    <Border>
        <TextBlock>This is a static data template</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I can reference this by:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="The file name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type system:Object}}" />
```

This remains just a complex key type.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx for reference.

Your DataTemplate must be an instantiated object to assign it to the CellTemplate property. Thats why you have to refer to your DataTemplate instance with help of `x:Key`.

Comment: -1 this does not answer the OP's question and has nothing to do with anything S:

Comment: Is "No" no answer? He asked if its possible. => No.

Comment: Please see my answer, turns out that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a example worked:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type this:TestData}"
                  DataType="{x:Type this:TestData}">

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" 
                 Background="Aquamarine" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" 
                        Width="*"                                        
                        CellTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type this:TestData}}" />
```

If in `CellTemplate` write `DynamicResource` it's will not work (as I tried at first).

In this case this line:

```
x:Key="{x:Type this:TestData}"
```

necessarily, without her example will not work. Although, when you're missing a key for `Style` or `DataTemplate`, this construction:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
```

automatically converted to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type local:MyType}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
```

This means that the `Style/DataTemplate` will be used explicitly for all controls of this type because in `ResourceDictionaries` can not be elements without keys, rather this is done to simplify the structure [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx).

Why in this situation does not work without a key? I think it is a bug, or have other restrictions that prevent him from working as it should, but it should work without a key.

Comment: So don't you use `x:Key` again? I mean you just named it in an odd way `{x:Type this:TestData}` but its still a reference to the instance by name. You could test this if you make the content of `x:Key` invalid like `x:Key="{x:Typexgarbagehere:TestData}"`and reference as resource.

Comment: @BlueM: "odd way" it is when you specify a simply `DataType` without key. In this case `x:Key` auto converted to implicitly of type like this: `x:Key="{x:Type this:TestData}"`,  because in ResourceDictionaries can not be elements without keys [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx). Why in this situation does not work without a key? I think it is a bug, or have other restrictions that prevent him from working as it should. But it should work without a key.

Comment: Because the key refers to an instance of the datatemplate. What you basically do is a sophisticated key to the instance of the template. Its still a single object thats referenced. Just the key is a special object in this case. Seems keys don't have to be strings only. In the same way the OP can also just use a string key. Its the same in the end. If I'm not mistaken the key is `typeof(TestData)`

Comment: Assuming that the OP wanted to lookup the Resource-DictionaryEntry by type, your answer is correct. Using it this way in XAML makes no sense though.

Comment: While I am thankful for the detailed sample I've updated my post to outline that your solution might be just like @BlueM said just a complex key name.

Comment: @Samuel: Most likely it is a bug (see my explanation), it should work without a key. Other alternatives I can not see.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a `DataGrid` does not support automatic data template selection by type in a template column. However, there is workaround that allows for this behavior. The key is to use a `ContentControl` as a nested element in a data template which is able to provide this mechanism.

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
         <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
         <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="DynamicTemplateColumnCellTemplate">
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DynamicTemplateColumnCellTemplate}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you want to scope the data templates for individual columns only, move them into the data template.

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <DataTemplate.Resources>
                  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
                     <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
                  </DataTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
                     <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataTemplate.Resources>
               <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

There is one issue with this approach. If `CanUserAddRows` is `True` and you use a collection of types with a parameterless constructor, the `DataGrid` will add an additional item, which does not match any data template type, so it is displayed as plain text via `ToString`, which is not what you want.

[image: Additional row with new item placeholder object.]

This obscure item comes from an internal property in `DataGrid`. It is defined like this ([reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,8656)):

```
internal static object NewItemPlaceholder
{
   get { return _newItemPlaceholder; }
}

private static object _newItemPlaceholder = new NamedObject("DataGrid.NewItemPlaceholder"); // Used as an alternate data item to CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder
```

In order to display the item correctly, you would have to detect this item, e.g. using a style trigger, but it is defined `internal`, so you cannot reference it directly. A marukp extension is one way to access it via reflection. Although this approach could break in the future and is somewhat dirty, it is an easy fix for the moment.

```
public class DataGridNewItemPlaceholderExtension : MarkupExtension
{
   public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      return typeof(DataGrid).GetProperty("NewItemPlaceholder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
   }
}
```

Using this markup extension, we can add a `DataTrigger` to the data template to set the `Content` of the nested `ContentControl` to the empty string, so it looks like the default new item row.

```
<DataGrid ... CanUserAddRows="True">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <DataTemplate.Resources>
                  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
                     <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
                  </DataTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType1}">
                     <!-- ...data template definition.--> 
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataTemplate.Resources>
               <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Content="{Binding}" />
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{local:DataGridNewItemPlaceholder}">
                     <Setter TargetName="ContentControl" Property="Content" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}" />
                  </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You could even define a separate data template for the new item placeholder.

```
<DataGrid ... CanUserAddRows="True">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <DataTemplate.Resources>
                  <!-- ...other data templates. -->
                  <DataTemplate x:Key="NewItemPlaceholderTemplate">
                     <!-- ...data template for the new item placeholder. -->
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataTemplate.Resources>
               <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Content="{Binding}" />
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{local:DataGridNewItemPlaceholder}">
                     <Setter TargetName="ContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NewItemPlaceholderTemplate}" />
                  </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```