# How to override contents of a cell with a circle if the bound property has a certain value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using a `DataGrid` to show prices of assets so I have many rows and columns. For example I show the current price like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="50" SortMemberPath="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Sometimes if the value is not valid, I just show `-`. What I want to do is to show a circle shape if the value of the bound property is `-`.

I can do this by adding a circle whose visibility is bound to a new property that checks if the price is invalid, and the opposite for the above text display. But the issue is that would require me to create new bindings per property which I am trying to avoid.

Is this maybe possible with triggers or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Text Value Converter

One way is to create a value converter that returns its parameter, if a value is not available (`-`).

```
public class ValueNotAvailableConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (value is string str) && str == "-" ? parameter : value;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a one-way conversion.");
   }
}
```

Then, you can use this converter for your binding and assign a glyph that fits a your requirements as converter parameter. To make this work, make sure that the font you use contains the glyph. In my case, Segoe UI contains a filled circle, which might be exactly what you want.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:ValueNotAvailableConverter x:Key="ValueNotAvailableConverter"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <!-- ...other columns. -->
      <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" SortMemberPath="Price" Binding="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource ValueNotAvailableConverter}, ConverterParameter=●}">
         <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
         </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <!-- ...other columns. -->
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</DataGrid>
```

### Template Column with Data Trigger

The same is possible with a template column, a style and a data trigger.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" SortMemberPath="Price">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Price, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock>
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Price}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Price}" Value="-">
                              <Setter Property="Text" Value="●"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
               </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### Template Column with Data Template Selector

If you need maximum flexibility, you can combine a template column with a data template selector. Please note that there are limitations in data grid template columns, like the `item` passed to the column is `null`, which requires a [workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b47ac38a-077f-41da-99b1-8b88add693d8/datagrid-celleditingtemplateselector-sendernull-always?forum=wpf). Since the data context of the template column is a whole data item form the `ItemsSource`, you have to check the `Price` property here.

```
public class PriceNotAvailableTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public string PriceAvailableTemplateKey { get; set; }

   public string PriceNotAvailableTemplateKey { get; set; }

   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (container is ContentPresenter contentPresenter &&
          contentPresenter.Parent is DataGridCell dataGridCell)
      {
         if (dataGridCell.DataContext is YourDataType data && data.Price == "-")
            return contentPresenter.FindResource(PriceNotAvailableTemplateKey) as DataTemplate;

         return contentPresenter.FindResource(PriceAvailableTemplateKey) as DataTemplate;
      }

      return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
   }
}
```

Now you can create different data templates when the price is available and when it is not.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:PriceNotAvailableTemplateSelector x:Key="PriceNotAvailableTemplateSelector"
                                               PriceAvailableTemplateKey="PriceAvailableTemplate"
                                               PriceNotAvailableTemplateKey="PriceNotAvailableTemplate"/>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="PriceAvailableTemplate">
         <TextBlock x:Name="ValueAvailable"  Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="PriceNotAvailableTemplate">
         <Ellipse x:Name="ValueNotAvailable" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50"
                              SortMemberPath="Price"
                              CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PriceNotAvailableTemplateSelector}">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Price, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### Automatic Data Template Selection

As you can see, the data template selector approach is very rigid and inflexible. A similar approach is to select the data template automatically by type. However, for this to work, you would have to create a dedicated type for a *price* and a type for *no price*. You can refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22513920/6181599) for more information, because the `DataGrid` has its quirks there, too, as you would expect.

### Template Column with Data Template and Trigger

Finally, a more hackish solution is to display both a `TextBlock` and an alternative element in a data template and change their visibility based on the `Price` value.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50"
                              SortMemberPath="Price">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Price, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="ValueAvailable" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                  <Ellipse x:Name="ValueNotAvailable" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Price}" Value="-">
                     <Setter TargetName="ValueAvailable" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                     <Setter TargetName="ValueNotAvailable" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using your last method and it works but when the circle is displayed it seems to scale the height of the entire row. Not sure why, because I am using the same shape with the same width and height of 8 in another column and they don't do that. I changed Collapsed to Hidden but still same result. Is it because of using StackPanel?